# Focus and enter editing in specific cell in ReadOnly DGV

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell

I'm trying make an option in `ContextMenuStrip` for my `DataGridView` which will allow to edit specific cell within the selected row, while the `DataGridView` is `ReadOnly` as default.

I have the following code which seems to work for other people, but not for me:

```
Private Sub Edit_ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Edit_ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If DGV_1.SelectedRows.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox("Please select only one item.")
    Else
        DGV_2.CurrentRow.Cells(2).ReadOnly = False
        DGV_2.CurrentCell = DGV_2.Item("Qty", DGV_2.CurrentRow.Index)
        DGV_2.BeginEdit(True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Bit more context - `DGV_2` values are based on selection within `DGV_1`, hence the `If` statement to only allow edit row cell `Qty` in `DGV_2` when its values are coming from only 1 selected row in `DGV_1`.

When this option is clicked, I want the user to be focused/entered into edit mode of the `Qty` cell within the selected row in `DGV_2`.

Comment: Don't make the grid read-only. Make every cell read-only. You can then make any cell you want read/write at any time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Would making columns `ReadOnly` in the `Form_Load` event work or does it have to be cell specific? If so how would I do it for cells, do I have to loop through all cells each time they change after `SelectedItem` in `DGV_1` changes?

Comment: You can test for yourself but I'm fairly sure that setting `ReadOnly` to `True` at any level means that setting it to `False` at a lower level will have no effect. If I'm right then a cell will always be read-only if its row, column or grid has its `ReadOnly` property set to `True`. If you want control at the cell level then you need to use the cell properties only.

Comment: @jmcilhinney … I have tested this for further clarification. If the  “grid’s” `ReadOnly` property is set to `true`… THEN as you note… setting any column, row or cell’s `ReadOnly` property to `false` has NO affect and the column, row or cell will remain read only. However, in my tests if you individually set each “columns” or “rows” `ReadOnly` property to `true` … THEN … you CAN set individual cell’s `ReadOnly` property to `false` and it will make the cell editable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Again, as per @jmcilhinney comments under the initial question, I was able to solve my issue by making `DGV_2.ReadOnly = False` and then configuring the below event:

```
Private Sub DGV_2_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DGV_2.RowsAdded
        If DGV_2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            DGV_2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).ReadOnly = True
            DGV_2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).ReadOnly = True
            DGV_2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).ReadOnly = True
            DGV_2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).ReadOnly = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Now the code I included in the initial question works.

Thanks again @jmcilhinney!

Comment: To make a column read only see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-make-columns-read-only-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: If you want to make the entire grid read only, you can still update a cell in code. Provide a TextBox or InputBox to get the new value for the cell from the user.